# Automaticly filling bits in c with f while doing "<<" operation

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I am having some fun with bit operations in C and i don't get one thing. If i have `char b = 0x6c`, and then I have `short y = 0x0000`, and I do `y=b; y = y << 12;`, why does it fill my `y` with `'f'`?

(editors note: the direction of `>>` and `<<` matters)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    short x = 0x0000;
    short y = 0x0000;
    char a = 0x00;
    char b = 0x00;
    char c = 0x00;

    a = 'a'; /// 61
    b = 'l'; /// 6c
    c = 'b'; /// 62

    x = a;
    x = x<<8;
    y = b;
    x = x + b;
    x = x >> 4;
    x = x << 4;

    y = y << 12;
    printf(" x + temp = %#06x y = %#06x\n", x, y);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: " have char b = 0x6c, and then i have short y = 0x0000, and I do y=b; y = y >> 12;, why does it fill my y with 'f'" I can not reproduce. y will be equal to 0.

Comment: Printf gives you y = 00000? Becouse in my case it is y = 0xffffc000

Comment: You need to read what you are writing.

Comment: Note: `%x` for unsigned int, `%hx` for unsigned short; neither for signed values. [See here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: *"I do y=b; y = y >> 12;1"*, No, you do not do `y` right-shift 12. Your code clearly shows `y` left-shift 12.

Comment: @MichałJagodzinski in my answer I explain why you see the numbers you do not understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a system with a 16-bit `int`, `y << 12` results in undefined behaviour because `y` has a signed type, and 0x6C000 is too large to fit in an `int`.

On a system with a 32-bit (or larger) `int` and a 16-bit `short`, `y = y << 12` results is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

The second paragraph probably applies to you.

Also, `%x` expects an `unsigned int`, not a `short`. So your `printf` also results in undefined behaviour.

So the program exhibits implementation-defined and/or undefined behaviour.

---

Fixed:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main( void ) {
   char a = 'a';  // 0x61
   char b = 'l';  // 0x6C
   char c = 'b';  // 0x62

   uint16_t x
      = ( ( (uint16_t)a & 0x00FF ) <<  8 )
      | ( ( (uint16_t)b & 0x00F0 ) <<  0 );

   uint16_t y
      = ( ( (uint16_t)b & 0x000F ) << 12 )
      | ( ( (uint16_t)c & 0x00FF ) <<  4 );

   // x = 6160 y = C620
   printf(" x = %04" PRIX16 " y = %04" PRIX16 "\n", x, y );

   return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K865T67Wb) on Compiler Explorer.

Comment: So how can i shift it?

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "shift it"? Or put differently, you didn't say what you want to achieve.

Comment: Well i want to divide 3 chars into 2 shorts. F.e. as in the code above i want to have            x = 0x6160 and y = 0xC620

Comment: You may want to use a type with greater capacity, like `unsigned int`

Comment: The width of `short` has little to do with the definedness of the expression `y << 12` for any `y`, because if the type of `y` has integer conversion rank less than that of `int` then its value is automatically converted to `int` or `unsigned int` prior to the shift being performed. However, assigning the result back to `y` is a different story.

Comment: @John Bollinger, woops! Fixed.

Comment: If you use unsigned short it also works btw, thanks for help!

Comment: Yes, but you want a 16-bit type, so it's clearer to use `uint16_t`.

Comment: `On a system with a 32-bit (or larger) int and a 16-bit short, y = y << 12 results is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.` no it is not implementation defined only it is UB : *"If E1 has a signed
type and nonnegative value, and E1 ´ 2E2 is representable in the result type, then that is
the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."*

Comment: @0___________. That was my original answer, and it's wrong as John Bollinger
 pointed out. E1 would be a 32-bit `int` (through promotion), and `0x6C000` fits in that.

Comment: it is still 16bits

Comment: No, @0___________, no, a 32-bit int has 32 bits.

Comment: @ikegami it probably is clearer to use but unfortunately not on my level :/, i am starting to learn basics on bit operations in C but i will definitly look into uint's, thanks again!

Comment: @Michał Jagodzinski, `uint16_t` is unsigned integer type that's exactly 16 bits in size. `unsigned short` has *at least* 16 bits. It could have more.

Comment: standards is about the original type not implicitly converted one. It does not fit and it is UB

Comment: @0___________, I used to this that too. But I've been taught otherwise. The spec is unclear, but it does says promotion happens first.

Comment: @0___________, It does make a lot more sense for it to based on the promoted type. The UB is there for the cases of overflow into the signed bit. Since the operation is being performed on the promoted operand, whether an overflow occurs or not is based on the promoted type. So whether UB occurs or not should be based on the promoted type.

Comment: Shift UB is opinion based. I keep my one.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the previous excellent languagewise [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75737580/15261315) I will explain what is happening using an example which does not invoke undefined behaviour, having the same behaviour.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned short x = 0x6c;
    short y;

    x <<= 12;
    y = x;

    printf("x = %u y = %d\n", x, y);
    printf("x = 0x%x y = 0x%x\n", (unsigned)x, (unsigned)y);
}
```

Result:

```
x = 49152 y = -16384
x = 0xc000 y = 0xffffc000
```

1. `x` has value `0x6c` when shifted left 12 bits it becomes `0xc000`.
2. `0xc000` assigned to signed short (two's complement system) is `-16384`
3. `-16384` in two's complement 32bit integer is `0xffffc000` and that is the reason you see this number

Comment: Yup, that was it in my case, thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

> If i have char b = 0x6c, and then i have short y = 0x0000, and I do y=b; y = y >> 12;, why does it fill my y with 'f'?

Given ...

```
char b = 0x6c;
short y = 0x0000;
y=b;
```

... the value then stored in `y` is `0x6c`.  Type `short` is required to be able to represent this value.

*Provided that type `int` can represent it*, the result of `y << 12` is then well defined as *an `int`* with value `0x6c000`.  C `int`s can be as narrow as 16 bits, which is not enough, but most implementations these days provide 32-bit `int`s, which is plenty.

However, few implementations provide `short`s longer than 16 bits, so it is unlikely that `y` can represent that result.  If it can't, then the assignment in ...

```
y = y << 12;
```

... either has an implementation-defined result or causes an implementation-defined signal to be raised.  Note: this is not *un*defined behavior.  Note 2: the requirements would be different for `unsigned short` or any other unsigned type.

The typical behavior for such an assignment is that the least-significant 16 bits are stored, and the others are lost.  That would give you the bit pattern `0xc000` stored in `y`, and as a value of a 16-bit two's complement `short`, that bit pattern represents a negative number (-16384 decimal).

When you attempt to print the result, the `short` value is implicitly converted to an `int` representation of the same value.  Your `int`s are apparently 32 bits wide, and a value-preserving widening of a negative two's complement representation requires filling the extra leading bits with 1s, not zeroes.  Thus, the third argument passed in ...

```
    printf(" x + temp = %#06x y = %#06x\n", x, y);
```

... is an `int` with the following bit pattern: `0xffffc000`.

**NOW** we come around to some undefined behavior. In `printf`, the argument value matched with a `%x` conversion specifier is required to be an `unsigned int`, but the actual value passed is a (`signed`) `int`.  Such a mismatch among `printf` parameters produces undefined behavior.  However, the usual manifestation of the undefined behavior in this specific kind of `int` / `unsigned int` mismatch is that the `int` bit pattern is interpreted as an `unsigned int` bit pattern.  The output you report is consistent with such a manifestation.

So what should you do?  For one thing, you should usually work with unsigned data types when doing shifts and bitwise manipulations.  For another thing, you should pay attention to the (minimum) widths of your data types, and be sure to use types that are wide enough for your purposes.  If you `#include <stdint.h>` then you (probably) will be able to use type `uint16_t`, which is an unsigned integer data type with exactly 16 bits, all value bits.  This does complicate your `printf` calls, however.  Alternatively, you could use `unsigned short`, an unsigned integer type with at least 16 value bits, and mask off all but the least-significant 16 bits.  Or even assume that your `unsigned short` has exactly 16 value bits -- that holds widely, though not universally.